# Cual es el similar de setw(40) << setfill('=') de C++ en C#?

Tags: c#, c++

Cuando estaba aprendiendo en C++, aprendi que con la biblioteca iomanip podia repetir caracteres de esta forma:

```
cout << setw(40) << setfill('=') << endl;
```

Ahora que estoy en C# no se como realizarlo o si es valido

Comment: En C++ era mucho más fácil `std::cout << std::string(40, '=') << '\n';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Su equivalente sería este:

```
string tabs = new String('=', n);
```

donde n es el número de veces que se va a repetir.

referencia [aquí, stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411752/best-way-to-repeat-a-character-in-c-sharp)